# meaning of double number sign and a command

Tags: unix

Say file has the value: `/usr/bin/ls`

```
${file##/*/}
```

How, after the following the command, the output is only `ls`?

Can't seem to understand the meaning of `##` ..

What is happening here?

Comment: This is a dumb way to implement `basename`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression removes anything that matches the pattern `/*/` from the beginning of the value of `file`.

`man bash`:

```
   ${parameter##word}
          Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
          a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
          the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of  the
          expansion  is  the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
          matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or the longest  matching  pat‐
          tern  (the  ``##''  case)  deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the
          pattern removal operation is applied to each positional  parame‐
          ter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If param‐
          eter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *,  the  pattern
          removal  operation  is  applied  to  each member of the array in
          turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```